# how can I import a gradle java module from android app and from java application

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project that contains a server and an android app, the server is java based. I want to create a gradle module for common java code that can be used by the server and the android app, I created the common module as a gradle java module and it seems that I can import this module as a dependency from both the server and the android app. 
My problem is that although gradle build is successful, intellij cannot find the dependencies from the java module in the android app.
Is there some way to do what I am trying or maybe intellij just doesn't support it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following configuration composed of `app`,`server` and `common` modules :

```
project/
├── app/
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── server/
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── common/
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

`settings.gradle` contains module listing :

```
include ':app',':server',':common'
```

If you have more subdirectories between modules like :

```
project/
├── server/
│   ├── subfolder
         ├── build.gradle
```

Your `settings.gradle` would look like :

```
include ':app',':server',':common'
project(':server').projectDir = new File('subfolder/server')
```

top level `build.gradle` include in the classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.XX` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Your app `build.gradle` has the `com.android.application` plugin with dependencies for your `server` and `common` modules. This is `app` module's `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':server')
    compile project(':common')
}
```

`server` and `common` modules are java module which can be used in Android project as well in Java project (in intellij-idea) with the `java` plugin. This is `server` and `common` module's `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    //for server module common module dependency :
    //compile project(':common')
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
    targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I am doing, but intellij has a problem with this setup and doesn't find the classes from 'common'